# Colocar imagens numa div com jquery

Tags: jquery

Como posso colocar determinadas imagens numa div usando jquery através de um clique no botão?

Segue o html:

```
         <div>
            <button id="btn2015" class="btn">2015</button>
            <button id="btn2014" class="btn">2014</button>
            <button id="btn2013" class="btn">2013</button>
            <button id="btn2012" class="btn">2012</button>
        </div>
        <div id="conteudo">

        </div>
```

Dependendo de cada botão clicado, a div conteudo será esvaziada e serão colocadas as imagens de acordo com o botão. Seguem os nomes das imagens:

```
imagem_piscina_2015.jpg
imagem_sala_2015.jpg
imagem_escrito_2015.jpg
```

Além dessas, existem várias outras com o mesmo nomes, só os anos terminando com os anos diferentes. Como posso fazer com que cada botão, chame apenas as imagens de acordo com os seus respectivos anos?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: eu fiz um evento de clique para cada botão. A primeira coisa que eu fazia era esvaziar a div conteudo. Depois tentei pegar o nome da imagem que está no mesmo diretório do arquivo, mas sem sucesso. :(

Comment: Uma imagem por botão ou 3 imagens por botão?

Comment: use atributo data nos botões e nele coloque a URL do seu SITE, algo como: `<button id="btn2015" class="btn" data-img="/imgs/imagem_piscina_2015.jpg">2015</button>`, assim no evento click, você ler o atributo e da um append na `div#conteudo`, ou já deixa uma imagem lá(com display:none), e troca o src com jquery `($("img").attr("src",link_img)` e da um efeito nela para aparecer, com `fadeIn(x)` onde x é o tempo em MS.

Comment: nesse caso 3, mas to tentando fazer de um jeito que se pegue o término da palavra, se clica no botão 2015, as imagens que terminem em 2015 aparecem, se for no botão 2014, as imagens que terminem em 2014 e assim por diante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa das demais para seu caso é:

> **@Edit**: Seguindo algumas sugestões, indicadas pelo amigo @Sergio,  de melhoria considerável no código, segue alterado

```js
var imagens = {
  2015: ['http://www.sulandes.com.br/painel/arquivos/categorias/7cbcd56e187b498d6dd7603cd8250b24.png', 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0FEJMBAc71c/VJbkENOA6qI/AAAAAAAAD2I/uYQiy_Xo5Us/s1600/2015-feliz%2Bano%2Bnovo-16.png'],
  2014: ['http://www.asacd.org.br/images/2014-calendrier.jpg', 'http://www.rio2016.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/switcher_710x450_rounded_corners/2014-foto_0.jpg'],
  2013: ['http://aclumontana.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2013.jpg', 'http://www.jornalistasconcurseiros.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/2013.jpg']
};

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  if(['2015', '2014', '2013'].indexOf(id) !== -1) {
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');
    conteudo.innerHTML = '';
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(imagens[id], function(arr) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = arr;
      conteudo.appendChild(img);
    });
    console.log(conteudo);
  }
});
```

```css
div img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="2015">2015</button>
<button id="2014">2014</button>
<button id="2013">2013</button>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Neste código foi declarado um objeto `images` contendo atributos com nome referente ao ano e valor contendo um array com a url das imagens. Também foi declarado uma event listener para detectar eventos de click referente aos botões, este evento chama uma função que verifica o ano, limpa o conteúdo anterior e percorrendo o array, cria elementos `<img>` atribuindo a url ao seu `src`.

> Veja funcionando aqui no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/gon2amby/)

Comment: Somente sugestão, acho que o código podia ser mais claro assim: https://jsfiddle.net/go221ezy/

Comment: @Sergio realmente, a validação de id que usou com certeza é mais "limpa", irei alterar meu código com base em sua sugestão, obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Fica uma sugestão:

```
var imagens = ['imagem_piscina_2015.jpg',
    'imagem_sala_2015.jpg',
    'imagem_escrito_2015.jpg'];

function criarImagem(nr) {
    return imagens.map(function (src) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = src.split('2015').join(nr);
        return img;
    });
}
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var ano = this.id.slice(3);
    $('#conteudo').html(criarImagem(ano));
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uasu6r9/

Este código faz com que cada vez que um botão seja carregado seja extraído o ano e passado a uma função. Essa função cria imagens (tantas quatos urls/nomes forem dados) e depois insere-as dentro da div `#conteudo`, re-escrevendo o seu conteúdo.

Sugiro adaptares `$('button')` para ser mais exato no seletor e também colocar os url corretos nas imagens para apontares para o sitio certo. Nessa array ou dentro da função, via uma variável de configuração.

Comment: Eu só não entendi o que você fez nessa linha `var ano = this.id.slice(3);`

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva a ideia é só usar o ano na string `btn2015`. Com o slice produzo uma nova string que começa depois das 3 primeiras letras. O `this` é o botão clicado e o `id` é a ID desse botão.

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugiro você criar um array, onde os indices serão os anos, e os valores suas respectivas imagens, algo como:

```
arr['2015'] = "imgs/img_de_2015, imgs/img2_de_2015";

arr['2016'] = "imgs/img_de_2016, imgs/img2_de_2016";
```

e no evento click do botão, você obter o ano no qual ele se refere(este você pode colocar no atributo data-ano por exemplo).

`<button class="btn_ano" data-ano="2015">2015</button>
$("button.btn_ano").click(function(){
ano = $(this).attr('data-ano');
imgs_arr = arr[ano].split(",");
});`

E logo após isso, fazer um laço para colocar as imagens na view, tipo:

`$(imgs_arr).each(function(i){
$("div#conteudo").append("<img src='"+imgs_arr[i]+"'/>");
});`

Claro, se ficar lento(muitas imagens), você pode passar para uma variável, e só depois dar um append na `div#conteudo`.

Algo como:

`imgs_html = "";
$(imgs_arr).each(function(i){
imgs_html.= "<img src='"+imgs_arr[i]+"'/>";
});
$("div#conteudo").append(imgs_html);`

Espero ter ajudado!